# Saving an Intellij project programmatically

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am working on an Intellij Plugin. When a button is pressed I would like to have the project save itself(like when the user modifies code) before the plugin executes. I can't seem to find a way to do this

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development is the best place to ask such questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FileDocumentManager.getInstance(project).saveAllDocuments()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ApplicationManager.getApplication().saveAll();